# Magento 2.1.7 New Sort Options Have Appeared by Themselves

Tags: magento-2.1.7, sorting, toolbar

We have recently noticed that two new sort options have appeared in our Sort By field. The options are "Discontinued Product" and "Product Name". I cannot find where in the code base these options would have been populated. Does anyone have a lead on how or where I can locate the origins of those two Sort By options?

Front end code from Inspector:

```
<div class="toolbar-sorter sorter">
<label class="sorter-label" for="sorter">Sort By</label>
<select id="sorter" data-role="sorter" class="sorter-options">
                <option value="position">
            Featured            </option>
                <option value="name">
            Product Name            </option>
                <option value="price" selected="selected">
            Price            </option>
                <option value="product_brand">
            Brand            </option>
                <option value="product_discontinued">
            Discontinued Product            </option>
        </select>
        <a title="High to Low" href="#" class="action sorter-action sort-desc" data-role="direction-switcher" data-value="asc">
        <span>High to Low</span>
    </a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Login to your Magento Admin and go to :

> Stores -> Attributes -> Products

find `product_discontinued` attribute from list and click on that row ( to edit )

Then Go to `Storefront Properties` tab ( under Attribute Information ) and go to bottom of the page and set "**Used for Sorting in Product Listing**" to **No**

Do same with product attribute `name`

It will remove both from Product List sorting drop down